# Does MetaMask do caching? How to flush?

Tags: testrpc, metamask

I'm running testrpc 3.0.5 locally on port 8454
Using Metamask 3.6.5

When I restart testrcp (and redeploy my contract) then my dapp still returns old values with Metamask. Without Metamask it works fine.

My current workaround is to connect Metamask to an other network then reconnect to localhost.

Is it some kind of caching by Metamask?

The workaround I'm doing is a bit time consuming when testing my Dapp. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed a current caching bug with MetaMask. Your current workaround is basically the best there is at the moment. This is being worked on actively, but it might take a little time, the recent rush of new users has left the MetaMask team slightly behind on the current backlog of bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Is there a ticket to follow?

Comment: @DanF is there a ticket to follow here?

Comment: Ticket here: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/2373